# Example to understand a possible invalid date through a CustomDateEditor with the exactDateLength option

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4, spring-mvc-initbinders

According with the CustomDateEditor API for this [constructor version](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomDateEditor.html#CustomDateEditor-java.text.DateFormat-boolean-int-):

```
public CustomDateEditor(DateFormat dateFormat,
                        boolean allowEmpty,
                        int exactDateLength)
```

says:

> Without an "exactDateLength" specified, the "01/01/05" would get parsed to "01/01/0005".

Assuming a length of 10, `01/01/05` fails how is expected. Tested and works

But about the following:

> However, even with an "exactDateLength" specified, prepended zeros in the day or month part may still allow for a shorter year part, so consider this as just one more assertion that gets you closer to the intended date format.

I don't understand the idea in a 100%. About the prepended zeros for the day or month, yes I know 0# (01-09) for a day or month. But how it could let write an invalid date yet?. Even when the exactDateLength is 10?. Because either `01/01/05` or `1/1/05` is smaller than 10

**What is the exactly idea in that sentence?** With an example, all would be better.